# Stop a YouTube Video in jQuery Mobile when using popup

Tags: jquery-mobile, youtube, popup, youtube-api

I embedded my video from youtube in a iFrame and opened it in a popup window. But after closing the window, the video is playing on.
How can I get use of the YouTube API in jQuery Mobile??

I embedded the iframe like this:

[See my file here](http://mobile.whykiki-kundenserver.de/startseite.html)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your particular issue but i found another post at stackoverflow here: [How to stop Youtube video playing when leaving a page on Jquery mobile site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503093/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-when-leaving-a-page-on-jquery-mobile-site)

Code something like this:

```
$(document).live('pagebeforehide', function(){
    player.pauseVideo();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

LOL, after investigating further. WHen you demo it on a mobile it behaves differently.
Video does stop when you leave the page. I was testing app on firefox on laptop (duh!)